# When submitting a new list to RecyclerView ListAdapter the diff check always returns true for areContentsTheSame()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I am using an MVVM architechture to build a simple ordering app. I am using a RecyclerView in my ProductsFragment to list all the products that can be ordered. I am also using LiveData in my ViewModel and observable in my Fragment to check for any changes to the List of products.

In my list item I have 3 buttons: 1 button to add a product to the basket, another to increment the quantity that customer wants to add to the basket and a third to decrement the quantity the customer wants to add to the basket.

In my product data class, whenever the customer clicks on increment or decrement button, the quantity is updated in the data model.

I am also using databinding to bind the product to the recyclerview list item layout and the click listeners. I am using the ListAdapter to get access to DiffUtil out of the box.

The problem I am having is that when the observable is notified I want to use the submitList method of the ListAdapter so only the item that has changed is updated in the RecyclerView. However, I have noticed that the DiffUtil method areContentsTheSame() always returns true. So the list item isn't updated. I don't want to use notifyDatasetChanged as this blocks the UI thread.

Another problem I am having is when I add a product to the basket, the reference to the product is being kept, so when I add a product to the basket, the MutableLiveData is also updated, when I just want MutableLiveData to be updated. How can I stop a reference to the LiveData being created when I add a product to the basket?

---

**ProductsViewModel**

```
class ProductsViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // LIVE DATA
    private val _basket = MutableLiveData<Basket>()

    val basket: LiveData<Basket>
        get() = _basket

    private val _products = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()

    val products: LiveData<List<Product>>
        get() = _products


    init {
        _basket.value = Basket()
        _products.value = dummyData
    }

    fun onIncrementProductQuantityButtonPressed(product: Product) {
        //product.quantity += 1
        //val newList = _products.value

        //_products.value = newList   
        val newProduct = product.copy(quantity = product.quantity.plus(1))
        _basket.value!!.updateProductInBasket(newProduct)
        _basket.value = _basket.value
    }

    fun onDecrementProductQuantityButtonPressed(product: Product) {
        if (product.quantity>1) {
            //product.quantity = product.quantity.minus(1)    
            val newProduct = product.copy(quantity = product.quantity.minus(1))
            _basket.value!!.updateProductInBasket(newProduct)
            _basket.value = _basket.value       
        }
    }
}
```

---

**ProductsFragment**

```
class ProductsFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: ProductsViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding: FragmentProductsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_products, container, false)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProductsViewModel::class.java)

        val adapter = ProductsAdapter(ProductListener { product, onClickType ->
            when(onClickType) {
                OnClickType.INCREMENT -> {
                    viewModel.onIncrementProductQuantityButtonPressed(product)
                }
                OnClickType.DECREMENT -> {
                    viewModel.onDecrementProductQuantityButtonPressed(product)
                }
                OnClickType.BASKET -> {
                    viewModel.addToBasketButtonPressed(product)
                }
            }
        })

        viewModel.products.observe(this, Observer { list ->
            adapter.submitList(list)
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // TODO: check why I have to do notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

        viewModel.basket.observe(this, Observer {
            activity?.invalidateOptionsMenu()
        })

        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.productsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return binding.root
    }
```

---

**ProductsAdapter**

```
class ProductsAdapter(private val clickListener: ProductListener) : ListAdapter<Product, ProductsAdapter.ProductViewHolder>(ProductDiffUtil()) {

    class ProductDiffUtil: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean {
            Log.d("Products", "Are items the same")
            return oldItem.name == newItem.name && oldItem.size == newItem.size
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean {
            Log.d("Products", "Are contents the same ${oldItem == newItem}")
            Timber.d("Are contents the same ${oldItem == newItem}")
            Timber.d("OLD ITEM: $oldItem")
            Timber.d("NEW ITEM: $newItem")
            return oldItem == newItem //need to check this
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        return ProductViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)

        //use holder to access all the views in the card item
        holder.bind(clickListener, item)
    }

    class ProductViewHolder private constructor(private val binding: LayoutProductCardBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(clickListener: ProductListener, item: Product) {
            binding.product = item
            binding.clickListener = clickListener
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ProductViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = LayoutProductCardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

                return ProductViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

}

class ProductListener(val clickListener: (product: Product, clickType: OnClickType) -> Unit) {
    fun onAddToBasket(product: Product) = clickListener(product, OnClickType.BASKET)
    fun onDecrementProductQuantity(product: Product) = clickListener(product, OnClickType.DECREMENT)
    fun onIncrementProductQuantity(product: Product) = clickListener(product, OnClickType.INCREMENT)
}


enum class OnClickType { BASKET, DECREMENT, INCREMENT  }
```

Comment: Hi @Pritam, I'm also using MVVM and I'm having the same issue. Can you post your changes to make it work?

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue seems to have a simple solution :). What you're doing is update only the value of the product that is passed to VM from view. What you **should** do is : create a copy of the product using .copy(quantity = ...) method, overwriting the quantity. Then replace your previous item in list and pass your new list to LiveData. This might also be the case why you need to actively call notifyDataSetChanged(as per your comment in code).

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Now I understand how LiveData works.

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Comment: Hi @r2rek, I'm having the same problem. And still didn't get how it works. Where should I do the .copy(...)? In the viewmodel or in fragment's livedata.observe before setting adapters data?

Comment: You do it in the viewmodel. I have updated my code in the question with the commented out lines in the viewmodel being the old code.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue recently. What I do basically is pass the HashMap<Integer, Object> changedMap using SingleLiveEvent. Creating a deep copy of list item can be memory consuming if you have too many fields in your class or lets say BitMap which are heavy in nature. Full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876118/diffutil-itemcallback-arecontentsthesame-always-returns-true-after-updating-an/64932645#64932645

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also create a new method called something like incrementProductInBasked(product.id) .

```
fun onIncrementProductQuantityButtonPressed(product: Product) {
        _basket.value!!.incrementProductInBasked(product.id)
        _basket.value = _basket.value
    }
```

I was having a similar issue. If your *product* is of type LiveData and you update *product*, your UI gets automatically updated. If you then also call *updateProductInBasket(product)* when you have an observer listening to changes to your basket, the new list that your observer will receive is already identical to the list on the UI.

So my suggestion is to drop the lines that update *product* and directly call a method (which I suggested *incrementProductInBasked(product.id)*) responsible to do the increment directly on your repository. The basket observer will then be called, and only the changed items will get updated on your RecyclerView list.